# Incorrect format of appendix TOC

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, appendices

I have this code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=0.33\baselineskip]{caption}

\captionsetup[table]{
    font=bf,
    size=normalsize,
    justification=centerlast,
    labelsep=newline
    }
\renewcommand\thetable{\Roman{table}}

\begin{document}
\listoftables
\appendix
\vspace{5ex}
\section{Appendix}
\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\Alph{section}.\Roman{table}}
\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\sisetup{table-format=2.2, group-separator={,}, group-minimum-digits=4}
\caption{\large{Some Data}}
\medskip\small\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                l
                S[table-format=-2.2]
           *{6}{S}
                }
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Description}}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Variable}}&
\multicolumn{5}{c}{More variables}\\\cmidrule{3-7}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{}&{Value 1}&{Value 2}&{Value 3}&{Value 4}&{Value 5}\\\midrule
Variable &11.11 &22.22 &33.33 &44.44 &55.55 &66.66\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\sisetup{table-format=2.2, group-separator={,}, group-minimum-digits=4}
\caption{\large{Some Data}}
\medskip\small\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                l
                S[table-format=-2.2]
           *{6}{S}
                }
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Description}}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Variable}}&
\multicolumn{5}{c}{More variables}\\\cmidrule{3-7}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{}&{Value 1}&{Value 2}&{Value 3}&{Value 4}&{Value 5}\\\midrule
Variable &11.11 &22.22 &33.33 &44.44 &55.55 &66.66\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\sisetup{table-format=2.2, group-separator={,}, group-minimum-digits=4}
\caption{\large{Some Data}}
\medskip\small\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                l
                S[table-format=-2.2]
           *{6}{S}
                }
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Description}}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Variable}}&
\multicolumn{5}{c}{More variables}\\\cmidrule{3-7}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{}&{Value 1}&{Value 2}&{Value 3}&{Value 4}&{Value 5}\\\midrule
Variable &11.11 &22.22 &33.33 &44.44 &55.55 &66.66\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\sisetup{table-format=2.2, group-separator={,}, group-minimum-digits=4}
\caption{\large{Some Data}}
\medskip\small\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                l
                S[table-format=-2.2]
           *{6}{S}
                }
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Description}}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Variable}}&
\multicolumn{5}{c}{More variables}\\\cmidrule{3-7}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{}&{Value 1}&{Value 2}&{Value 3}&{Value 4}&{Value 5}\\\midrule
Variable &11.11 &22.22 &33.33 &44.44 &55.55 &66.66\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\sisetup{table-format=2.2, group-separator={,}, group-minimum-digits=4}
\caption{\large{Some Data}}
\medskip\small\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                l
                S[table-format=-2.2]
           *{6}{S}
                }
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Description}}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Variable}}&
\multicolumn{5}{c}{More variables}\\\cmidrule{3-7}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{}&{Value 1}&{Value 2}&{Value 3}&{Value 4}&{Value 5}\\\midrule
Variable &11.11 &22.22 &33.33 &44.44 &55.55 &66.66\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\sisetup{table-format=2.2, group-separator={,}, group-minimum-digits=4}
\caption{\large{Some Data}}
\medskip\small\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                l
                S[table-format=-2.2]
           *{6}{S}
                }
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Description}}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Variable}}&
\multicolumn{5}{c}{More variables}\\\cmidrule{3-7}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{}&{Value 1}&{Value 2}&{Value 3}&{Value 4}&{Value 5}\\\midrule
Variable &11.11 &22.22 &33.33 &44.44 &55.55 &66.66\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\sisetup{table-format=2.2, group-separator={,}, group-minimum-digits=4}
\caption{\large{Some Data}}
\medskip\small\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                l
                S[table-format=-2.2]
           *{6}{S}
                }
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Description}}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Variable}}&
\multicolumn{5}{c}{More variables}\\\cmidrule{3-7}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{}&{Value 1}&{Value 2}&{Value 3}&{Value 4}&{Value 5}\\\midrule
Variable &11.11 &22.22 &33.33 &44.44 &55.55 &66.66\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

which produces this output

[image: Table]

In my report, I have about 15 tables listed in the appendix (with roman numerals). I have been able to reset the table counter and add "A." to the table numbering. However, when I add multiple tables, the table number and name overlap in the list of tables.

Does anyone have an idea how I can use a format similar to the one that I am using right now, but where it does not overlap? (Sorry for duplicating the tables in this way, I didn't know how to show the list of tables otherwise.) Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could redefine `\l@table`:

```
\makeatletter
  \renewcommand*\l@table{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{3em}}
\makeatother
```

The first length (default: 1.5em) is the indentation of the table entry and the second length is the horizontal space for the table number (default: 2.3em). So you have to adjust the third argument of `\@dottedtocline` for `\l@table`.

[image]

Alternatively you could use a package like `tocbasic`, `tocloft` etc.

Package `tocbasic` can calculate the horizontal space needed for the numbers:

```
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[dynnumwidth]{tocline}{table}
```

But note that this calculation needs an additional run.